# How to cover test cases for Svg react component using Jest + Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am relatively new to react testing. Any help/advice is appreciated. I have this simple `PencilIcon` component. I saw the test coverage report and the bold text below indicates that those bold text or lines of code are not covered in test coverage.

How do i ensure test coverage happens for those lines of text. Can someone point me how to write test cases for the bold text below.

I am not able to make the code bold. Basically this below line of code is not covered in test coverage report.

```
const classNames = getClasses({ styles, classes: ['pencilIcon'], className, brand })***
  return (
```

And here is the full component

```
import React from 'react'
import { getClasses } from '../es/lib'
import SvgIcon from '../SvgIcon'
import styles from './PencilIcon.less'

const PencilIcon = ({ brand, className, ...keepProps }) => {
  const classNames = getClasses({ styles, classes: ['pencilIcon'], className, brand })
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...keepProps} className={classNames} viewBox="0 0 44 44">
      <path d="M18.999 31.396l-6.83 2.704a8.362 8.362 0 0 0-.868-1.026 8.535 8.535 0 0 0-1.438-1.148l2.74-6.924-1.208-1.209-5.127 12.954a.764.764 0 0 0 .16.826.764.764 0 0 0 .825.16l12.955-5.128-1.209-1.209zM36.949 11.929L32.07 7.051a2.87 2.87 0 0 0-2.029-.841c-.734 0-1.469.28-2.029.841l-15.8 15.803 8.937 8.937L33.56 19.377l3.39-3.39a2.869 2.869 0 0 0-.001-4.058zm-10.799.038l2.237 2.238L17.503 25.09l-2.237-2.236L26.15 11.967zm-5.002 16.768l-2.117-2.117 10.885-10.886 2.116 2.116-10.884 10.887z" />
    </SvgIcon>
  )
}

PencilIcon.defaultProps = {
  title: 'Edit',
  width: '44px',
  height: '44px'
}

export default PencilIcon
```

And here is the `getClasses` imported into above component.

```
export const getClasses = ({
  styles = {},
  classes = [],
  className = '',
  brand = '',
  device = {}
}) => {
  const classesInStyles = classes.concat([brand]).filter(_class => !!_class).map(name => styles[name]);

  if (device.platform) {
    classesInStyles.push(styles[device.platform === '7P' ? 'desktop' : 'mobile']);
    device.keyboardOpen && classesInStyles.push(styles.keyboard);
  }

  return [...classesInStyles, className].join(' ').trim();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest importing this line from a different file and excluding it from your test coverage.

```
<SvgIcon {...keepProps} className={classNames} viewBox="0 0 44 44">
  <path d="M18.999 31.396l-6.83 2.704a8.362 8.362 0 0 0-.868-1.026 8.535 8.535 0 0 0-1.438-1.148l2.74-6.924-1.208-1.209-5.127 12.954a.764.764 0 0 0 .16.826.764.764 0 0 0 .825.16l12.955-5.128-1.209-1.209zM36.949 11.929L32.07 7.051a2.87 2.87 0 0 0-2.029-.841c-.734 0-1.469.28-2.029.841l-15.8 15.803 8.937 8.937L33.56 19.377l3.39-3.39a2.869 2.869 0 0 0-.001-4.058zm-10.799.038l2.237 2.238L17.503 25.09l-2.237-2.236L26.15 11.967zm-5.002 16.768l-2.117-2.117 10.885-10.886 2.116 2.116-10.884 10.887z" />
</SvgIcon>
```

Comment: this is like avoiding the situation

Comment: svg are images.
you don't test images.

hundred 100% code-coverage is no point if you are testing the wrong code.

In this case, what you want to test is that you passed the correct props on the component, and you can do that on the component calling this one.

Comment: okay. but how do i cover test cases for const classNames = getClasses({ styles, classes: ['pencilIcon'], className, brand }) ? that is where coverage report shows pending coverage